# How to configure a script to start automatically after server reboot

Tags: server, scripts, cron

I want to configure a script to execute automatically when a server is rebooted. Currently I need to start the script manually after server reboot. I am using Amazon Linux server.

I was able to configure the script to start automatically on my local ubuntu System as:

1. I started terminal and typed `crontab -e`
2. I added `@reboot path/to/script` and saved it.

After restart the script started automatically on my local machine.

When I try to do same on server crontab file is not opened.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/), not cron. Upstart is what's used to run commands at startup (and shutdown).